# How to implement draggble date in flutter using show datepicker

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I am using showdaterangepicker one of the flutter widget. I made change in the library to achieve the way UI I want but now I want draggable feature in the application how to do it. I think I have to do it in

```
dayWidget = InkResponse(
        focusNode: _dayFocusNodes[day - 1],

        onTap: () => widget.onChanged(dayToBuild),
        radius: _monthItemRowHeight / 2 + 4,
        splashColor: colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.38),
        onFocusChange: _dayFocusChanged,
        child: dayWidget,
      );
```

I want feature similar to makemytrip mobile app calendar

Comment: can you share the UI?

Comment: i shared the ui